# Path Selection Component in MFC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I have an Edit box in my dialog application in MFC. I use this component to select path. I can edit path. Can I provide suggestion functionality in this control. That is when user edits the path, component provides the user with possible suggestions depending on the input?? or Can I achieve this functionality using ComboBox Control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OnInitDialog() where m_pathEdit is your CEdit control:

```
SHAutoComplete(m_pathEdit.m_hWnd, SHACF_DEFAULT);
```

Before calling your dialog's DoModal():

```
CoInitialize(NULL);
```

and after returning from DoModal():

```
CoUninitialize();
```

then your edit control has autocompletion of URLs and file paths.

Comment: I have a simple MFC Dialog Application. I am not using DoModal() for separate Dialog. So in my case where Should I put  CoInitialize(NULL); and CoUninitialize(); calls? Thanks

Comment: @Sarfraz `InitInstance()` of your app class. This already exists for you in a different .cpp file to your dialog, and is where your dialog is started from.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I want to only Show Directories in the Edit Control. But When I use it with SHACF_FILESYS_DIRS flag. It Show nothing. Discard the previous comment.

Comment: @Sarfraz: I suspect you've either placed the `SHAutoComplete` before the base class OnInitDialog or you haven't wrapped the DoModal between the CoInitialize and CoUninitialize. Put SHAutoComplete just before your OnInitDialog returns TRUE, and ensure DoModal in the InitInstance is between the CoInitialize and CoUninitialize.